# How can I use fields of a variable of type "record" in another "insert" query?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a DB with a composite key, and another table references that key. Reduced to a very simple example (leaving out *all* the irrelevant cruft for this example) between network hosts and their ports, this becomes something like this:

```
       host
---------+--------
scope    | TEXT
hostname | TEXT

       port
---------+--------
scope    | TEXT    <-- Referencing host.scope
hostname | TEXT    <-- Referencing host.hostname
name     | TEXT
```

I would like to avoid duplicating the values of `scope` and `hostname` in an SQL script. So I figured that I can write and `INSERT ... RETURNING ... INTO ...` statement, and then reuse the returned record in the inserts for ports. So I came up with the following:

```
BEGIN;
    DO $$
        DECLARE
            result RECORD;
        BEGIN
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE host (
                scope TEXT,
                hostname TEXT
            );
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE port (
                scope TEXT,
                hostname TEXT,
                name TEXT
            );
            INSERT INTO host (scope, hostname) VALUES ('scope-a', 'hostname')
                RETURNING (scope, hostname) INTO result;
            RAISE NOTICE 'result = %', result;

            INSERT INTO port (scope, hostname, name) VALUES (result.*, 'port-1');
        END
    $$;
ROLLBACK;
```

I have considered using separate variables, which will work, but the real script would benefit in readability and maintainability when using a composite type like `RECORD`.

I also tried using a `ROWTYPE`, but some tables contain `NOT NULL` constraints which somehow prevent me from declaring variables with that type.

The final `INSERT` statement in the example above fails. The `result.*` syntax is something I blindly tried without any luck. Because it is a "RECORD" type, PostgreSQL doesn't know the structure which might be a reason why this fails.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `record`, but individual variables for the two values:

```
INSERT INTO host ...
   RETURNING scope, hostname INTO v_scope, v_hostname;

INSERT INTO port (scope, hostname, name)
   VALUES (v_scope, v_result, 'port-1');
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but was wondering if this is possible with a composite type. The real DB has quite a few more columns and tables, and being able to use composite types like `RECORD` would make the script so much more manageable. I also tried to use a `ROWTYPE` but some tables contain `NOT NULL` constraints which fire when declaring the variables as such.

Comment: I understand the pain, but you will have to write out all columns.

Comment: bummer :) I will leave the question open just for a few more minutes before accepting your answer. Just in case ;)

Comment: You could select your values into a record. So you do not need to declare one variable for each column. But for inserting, you need to list all the fields of the record by hand like ```VALUES (result.scope, result.hostname, ...)```

Comment: @Islingre this would work with `ROWTYPE`, but as far as I can tell, `RECORD` does not include enough information to allow this to work.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, I stumbled on [a post in the PG mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTikSnHJDFrtmEVIS2lJLLvbBcVif75fP7ReX2SWD@mail.gmail.com) which mentioned that domain with a `NOT NULL` constraint are a bad idea. This was part of my problem. Removing that allows me to use `ROWTYPE` instead of `RECORD`.